# Counting sequenced records in ranges, based on grouped varchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to calculate count of same values, in a certain pattern, where the pattern might occur again.

To simply, please see below data, and expected result.
Solution is implemented in SQL Server 2016 and above ...

```
DECLARE @dataTable TABLE
                   (
                       ts DATETIME, 
                       prop1 VARCHAR(4), 
                       prop2 VARCHAR(2)
                   );

INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:51:00', 'AAAA', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:50:00', 'AAAA', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:49:00', 'AAAA', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:48:00', 'BBBB', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:47:00', 'BBBB', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:46:00', 'BBBB', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:45:00', 'AAAA', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:44:00', 'AAAA', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:43:00', 'AAAA', '02');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:32:00', 'AAAA', '02');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:41:00', 'CCCC', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:40:00', 'CCCC', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:39:00', 'CCCC', '02');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:38:00', 'BBBB', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:37:00', 'BBBB', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:36:00', 'BBBB', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:35:00', 'AAAA', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:34:00', 'AAAA', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:33:00', 'CCCC', '02');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:32:00', 'CCCC', '02');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:31:00', 'CCCC', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:30:00', 'CCCC', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:29:00', 'CCCC', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:28:00', 'CCCC', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:27:00', 'CCCC', '01');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:26:00', 'CCCC', '02');
INSERT INTO @dataTable (ts, prop1, prop2) VALUES ('2023-05-01 10:25:00', 'CCCC', '02');

SELECT 
    *, 
    MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY prop1 ORDER BY ts DESC), 
    COUNT(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY prop1 ORDER BY ts DESC )
FROM 
    @dataTable 
ORDER BY 
    ts DESC;
```

The blocks are sequenced based on ts column.

The expected result should look like:

| MAX_OF_PROP1_IN_BLOCK | PROP1 | PROP2 | COUNT_PROP1_IN_BLOCK | COUNT_OF_PROP2_IN_BLOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 10:51:00 | AAAA | 01 | 3 | 3 |
| 2023-05-01 10:48:00 | BBBB | 01 | 3 | 3 |
| 2023-05-01 10:45:00 | AAAA | 01 | 4 | 2 |
| 2023-05-01 10:45:00 | AAAA | 02 | 4 | 2 |
| 2023-05-01 10:41:00 | CCCC | 01 | 3 | 2 |
| 2023-05-01 10:41:00 | CCCC | 02 | 3 | 1 |
| 2023-05-01 10:38:00 | BBBB | 01 | 3 | 3 |
| 2023-05-01 10:35:00 | AAAA | 01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-05-01 10:33:00 | CCCC | 02 | 9 | 2 |
| 2023-05-01 10:33:00 | CCCC | 01 | 9 | 5 |
| 2023-05-01 10:33:00 | CCCC | 02 | 9 | 2 |

I've tried experimenting with window functions, but I'm keep getting always count/max values based on prop1/prop2 within whole scope, and not in ranges defined by prop1/prop2 values.
It is possible to preorganized data with CTE query before...

```
SELECT * 
, MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY prop1 ORDER BY ts DESC)
, COUNT(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY prop1 ORDER BY ts DESC )
FROM @dataTable
ORDER BY ts DESC;
```

I believe the solution is quite simple, but after several tries, and searching the internet, I could not find appropriate example. I believe, RANGE should be used, but I could not get this to work.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that having two rows with `10:32:00` is a typo, you have a *gaps and islands* problem.

The method I prefer is to set a flag by using `lag` whenever the value in the next row is different, then sum this to provide a running total that represents each *island*; with this in place you can then count and aggregate the final data.

See this [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F5Yl1u0h)

```
with diff as (
  select *, 
    case when lag(prop1) over(order by ts desc ) = prop1 then 0 else 1 end gp1,
    case when lag(prop2) over(order by ts desc ) = prop2 then 0 else 1 end gp2
  from t
), grp as (
  select *, 
    Sum(gp1) over(order by ts desc) grp1, Sum(gp2) over(order by ts desc) grp2
  from diff
)
select Max_Of_Prop_In_Block, prop1, prop2, 
  grp1Count Count_Of_Prop1_In_Block, 
  grp2Count Count_Of_Prop2_In_Block
from (
  select *, 
    Max(ts) over(partition by grp1) Max_Of_Prop_In_Block, 
    Count(*) over(partition by grp1) grp1Count, 
    Count(*) over(partition by grp1, grp2) grp2Count
  from grp
)t
group by Max_Of_Prop_In_Block, grp1Count, prop1, prop2, grp2Count, grp2
order by Max_Of_Prop_In_Block desc, Max(grp2);
```

Comment: Hey Stu! Thank you for your fast reply. Yes, of course, same ts was a typo.
At this moment ,after modification, seems that it is a perfect solution :-) Thank you very much!